# Saving Div's Array content to a MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have table with input arrays and 1 div array. Of course i have no problem saving the input arrays to the database but when i do the same procedure for a div, its not working. When i view the column in the database, its blank.

```
<td><div name="partamount[]" id="partamount[]" class="amount" ></div> </td>
```

when you inspect the element:

[image: Screenshot]

PHP

```
$partamount = $_POST['partamount'];
$partamountarray = implode( ", ", $partamount);



$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO invoices(partamount, login_id) VALUES('$partamountarray', '$loginId')");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>` elements are not form elements so they don't get passed. You should rather use some `<input>` element or use javascript to populate an `<input type="hidden">` field with the same data as your `<div>` element have.